# YQL two requests for paging/limit

Tags: yql

I'm playing around with a XML API where the search doesn't support paging/limit. The recommended way is to just request all the IDs and then in a second request get the data and handle paging on your own.

First request:

```
http://example.com?search=foobar&columns=ID

<results>
  <item><id>1</id></item>
  <item><id>2</id></item>
  <item><id>3</id></item>
  <item><id>4</id></item>
  <item><id>5</id></item>
  <item><id>6</id></item>
  <item><id>7</id></item>
  <item><id>8</id></item>
  <item><id>9</id></item>
  <item><id>10</id></item>
</results>
```

Second request:

```
http://example.com?search=1,2,3,4,5&columns=ID,title,description

<results>
  <item><id>1</id><title>foobar</title><description /></item>
  <item><id>2</id><title>foobar</title><description /></item>
  <item><id>3</id><title>foobar</title><description /></item>
  <item><id>4</id><title>foobar</title><description /></item>
  <item><id>5</id><title>foobar</title><description /></item>
</results>
```

Is it possible with YQL to combine this into a single request with a search result count and paging support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a YQL table with paging:

```
<paging model="offset" matrix="true">  
    <start id="internalIndex" default="0" />  
    <pagesize id="internalPerPage" max="250" />
</paging>
```

Use Javascript to handle the two fetches and the paging:

```
var internalIndex = parseInt( request.matrixParams['internalIndex'] );
var internalPerPage = parseInt( request.matrixParams['internalPerPage'] );

var interimURL = 'http://example.com?columns=ID';
interimURL += '&search=' + request.queryParams['search'];
var interimQueryParameter = {url:interimURL};
var interimQuery = y.query("SELECT * FROM xml WHERE url=@url", interimQueryParameter);

var rows = interimQuery.results.*;

// get subset
var xml    = rows;//this.copy(); // clone XML
var from = internalIndex;
var to = ((from + internalPerPage) < xml.length()) ? (from + internalPerPage) : xml.length();
var sliced = [];
for (; from < to; from++) {
    sliced.push(xml[from].@["ID"]);
}

var finalURL = 'http://example.com?';
finalURL += '&search=' + sliced.join(",");
finalURL += "&columns=ID,title,description"
var finalQueryParameter = {url:finalURL};
var finalQuery = y.query("SELECT * FROM xml WHERE url=@url", finalQueryParameter);

var finalResults = finalQuery.results.response;
finalResults.node += <internalCurserPositon>{internalIndex}</internalCurserPositon>
finalResults.node += <internalCount>{rows.length()}</internalCount>

response.object = finalResults;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a straight forward way from the documentation but you could do this:

1) Create a YQL table A which queries http://example.com?search=foobar&columns=ID
2) Create a YQL table B which queries http://example.com?search=1,2,3,4,5&columns=ID,title,description
3) Now, create a YQL table C which does a y.query on join of A and B like so:

> select * from B where search in (select ids from A where search="foobar")

Ofcourse the query syntax will change based on table name and keys defined in it. For more information on YQL join refer [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/joins.html)

Hope this is clear and if you find something better in this case, do let me know :)

Comment: Karan, thx for taking the time to answer this. Your suggestion doesn't take paging into account. See my answer for the javascript solution to this.